# Optional dependencies using test-requirements.txt in pyproject.toml with setuptools

Tags: python, dynamic, setuptools, requirements.txt, pip-tools

A typical `pyproject.toml` using `setuptools` with [optional dependencies](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#optional-dependencies) looks like the following (unrelated sections removed):

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "my_project"
dependencies = ["numpy","pandas"]

[project.optional-dependencies]
fast = ["numba"]
test = ["pytest"]
```

To use a `requirements.txt` (generated from `pip-compile` using `requirements.in`) to store the main dependencies (without adding other files such as `setup.py`), one can use the `dynamic` keyword:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "my_project"
dynamic = ["dependencies"] # Changed

[project.optional-dependencies]
fast = ["numba"]
test = ["pytest"]

[tool.setuptools.dynamic] # New section
dependencies = {file = ["requirements.txt"]}
```

If I would like `setuptools` to also read the optional dependencies from other files (say, `test-requirements.txt`), what should be the correct syntax? According to [the documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html#dynamic-metadata), the feature is in beta, and only a single keyword `optional-dependencies` is exposed. But I have more than one optional dependencies: `[fast]` and `[test]`, and their `*-requirements.txt` are generated in a fixed format from `pip-compile`. Specifically, what is meant by `group` in:

> *subset* of the `requirements.txt` format **per group**

?

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution from an example in [`pip-tools`'s GitHub](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools#requirements-from-pyprojecttoml). Adapting it to my example:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "my_project"
dynamic = ["dependencies", "optional-dependencies"]

[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
dependencies = { file = ["requirements.in"] }
optional-dependencies.fast = { file = ["fast-requirements.txt"] }
optional-dependencies.test = { file = ["test-requirements.txt"] }
```

I do not understand why in the example one file is `.in` and the others are `.txt`, but this will do for now. In fact, to avoid version conflicts (even with `pip-sync`), eventually in my repository I swapped the above example code the other way around: use the version-pinned `requirements.txt`, but turning the optional dependencies into `.in`.